# Cocoapods and Swift compiling and able to debug but functionality not working

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, cocoalumberjack

I'm pretty new to iOS development as a whole. I've started a project in swift and am using Cocoapods with Lumberjack for logging.

I've successfully created a pod file and am using the workspace having run `pod install`.

I've imported cocoa lumberjack and added TTY and ASL log appenders and a file log appender. I have some logging lines as well.

The app compiles fine (clean and build) and loads fine on both iPhone and simulator. I can even debug the calls to lumberjack as they are called. Obviously the library is linked up ok. However nothing is displayed in the console window of Xcode and no log files get created.

Maybe I'm missing configuration somewhere or something is preventing it from working, but I'm stuck completely.

I've tried removing cocoapods recompiling (which fails) and reinstalling cocoapods over and over. Still nothing. Any suggestions?

**EDIT 15/04/16**

Here is my `pod file`:

```
platform :ios, ‘9.3’
use_frameworks!

target 'ClientIntegrationAppExample' do

pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'

end

target 'ClientIntegrationAppExample Tests' do

end

target 'ClientIntegrationAppExample UITests' do

end
```

And Example usage in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(application: UIApplication) {
    DDLog.addLogger(DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance()) // TTY = Xcode console
    DDLog.addLogger(DDASLLogger.sharedInstance()) // ASL = Apple System Logs

    let fileLogger: DDFileLogger = DDFileLogger() // File Logger
    fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60*60*24  // 24 hours
    fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7
    DDLog.addLogger(fileLogger)

    DDLogError("Error message")
    DDLogWarn("Warn message")
    DDLogInfo("Info message")
    DDLogDebug("Debug message")
    DDLogVerbose("Verbose message")

    ....
}
```

Comment: Xcode shows logs only when we log something in code... Logs show when you are using NSLog or some warning occurring in code or  code produce any error only

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma Not true. You can use a swift wrapper, a bridging header and ASL to display log lines at different log levels in Xcode. I've done exactly that before - but need to use a better framework for logging. You can also display lumberjack DDLog statements in Xcode by attaching DDTTYLogger and DDASLogger which I have done as per documentation here: https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/README.md